# Searching a text and automatically scroll down

Tags: search, javafx, scroll

I have to code a full text search. If the word is found it's highlighted and if I press the 'Next' button the next word in the text is highlighted and so on. But the challange is, that the words further down in the text have to be highlighted in the middle of the window. Means, the text has to scroll automatically to the highlighted word. I read a few posts on Stackoverflow but I couldn't get it to work.

This is my find methode:

```
   findButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                errorText.setText("");
                if (textFieldFind.getText() != null) {
                    findWord = Pattern.compile(textFieldFind.getText(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    matcher = findWord.matcher(textArea.getText());
                    if (matchCase.isSelected()) {
                        findWord = Pattern.compile(textFieldFind.getText());
                        matcher = findWord.matcher(textArea.getText());
                    }
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        textArea.selectRange(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                        textArea.scr
                    } 
                } else {
                    errorText.setText("Missing search key");
                } 
            }
        });
```

This is my 'Next' button methode:

```
      nextButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    scroll.setVvalue(0.5); 
                    textArea.selectRange(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you include any of the code you have used so far so we can help debug the issue with the code you tried or see what you are trying to do more clearly? From what i understand you want to highlight the text in a textbox not in a list? and when a word is found in the text, have it auto-scroll so the word is then visible?

Comment: Yes, auto-scroll so the word is in the middle of the window. At the moment, the highlighted word is visible, but at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I am guessing here, but maybe you can use textarea.setScrollTop(positionOfMatchInt); I would play with the numbers positionOfMatchInt - 100. In your case textArea.setScrollTop(matcher.start());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Platform.runLater(()->textArea.setScrollTop(matcher.start()));
```

This worked for me